How to get JSON output from gemini in colab for langgraph agent use case
I am coding an agent in colab using python & I want gemini to return me the output as JSON but it is not happening. I am using langchain_google_genai library. Here is the reference I used. https://ai.google.dev/gemini-api/docs/json-mode?lang=python
import typing_extensions as typing
class JsonContent(typing.TypedDict):
  content: str

.......
from langchain_google_genai import GoogleGenerativeAI
model = GoogleGenerativeAI(model="gemini-1.5-pro",generation_config={"response_mime_type": "application/json","response_schema": list[JsonContent]})

.......
PLAN_PROMPT = """You are an expert writer tasked with writing a high level outline of an essay. \
Write such an outline for the user provided topic. Give an outline of the essay along with any relevant notes \
or instructions for the sections."""

.....
messages = [
    {"role": "system", "content": PLAN_PROMPT},
    {"role": "user", "content": f"research question: what is the difference between langchain and langsmith."}
]
response = model.invoke(messages)
print(response)

When I print the value it is giving raw text and not JSON.
## Essay Outline: LangChain vs. LangSmith: Navigating the Landscape of LLM Application Development

**I. Introduction**
    * Briefly introduce Large Language Models (LLMs) and their growing role in application development.
    * Highlight the challenges of building with LLMs, especially for complex applications.
    * Introduce LangChain and LangSmith as two prominent tools addressing these challenges.
    * **Note:** Keep this section concise and engaging, setting the stage for a comparative analysis.

**II. Understanding LangChain: The Building Blocks of LLM Apps**
    * **What is LangChain?** 
        * Define LangChain as a framework with pre-built modules for common LLM tasks.
        * Emphasize its focus on flexibility and customization.
    * **Key Features and Components:**
        * Briefly explain key modules like Prompts, Chains, Agents, and Memory.
        * Provide simple code examples (if applicable) to illustrate their use.
    * **Use Cases and Advantages:**
        * Discuss scenarios where LangChain excels (e.g., chatbots, question answering).
        * Highlight its strengths: modularity, ease of integration, and active community.
    * **Note:** Aim for clarity and conciseness, focusing on the core functionalities.

**III. Exploring LangSmith: The Debugging and Observability Powerhouse**
    * **What is LangSmith?**
        * Define LangSmith as a platform for debugging, evaluating, and improving LLM apps.
        * Emphasize its focus on understanding and optimizing LLM behavior.
    * **Key Features and Capabilities:**
        * Explain features like tracing LLM calls, visualizing execution flows, and analyzing performance.
        * Discuss its tools for debugging errors, identifying biases, and improving prompt design.
    * **Use Cases and Advantages:**
        * Highlight how LangSmith benefits development workflows and ensures application quality.
        * Emphasize its strengths: observability, debugging tools, and performance optimization.
    * **Note:**  Focus on how LangSmith complements the development process, not just as a debugging tool.

**IV.  LangChain and LangSmith: A Synergistic Relationship**
    * **Complementary Nature:**
        * Explain how LangChain and LangSmith address different aspects of LLM development.
        * Emphasize that they are not mutually exclusive but can be used together effectively.
    * **Integration Points:**
        * Discuss how LangSmith can be integrated into LangChain workflows for enhanced debugging and observability.
        * Provide examples of how this integration benefits developers.
    * **Note:**  Highlight the value of using both tools in tandem for a more robust development process.

**V.  Conclusion**
    *  Summarize the key differences and strengths of LangChain and LangSmith.
    *  Reiterate their complementary nature and the benefits of using them together.
    *  Provide a concluding statement about the evolving landscape of LLM development and the importance of tools like LangChain and LangSmith.
    *  **Note:**  End with a forward-looking perspective on the future of LLM application development. 

How to make model to return JSON? If I say print(response.content) it should print the content but when I do so it is throwing:
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-67-1db71bf23451> in <cell line: 6>()
      4 ]
      5 response = model.invoke(messages)
----> 6 print(response.content)

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'content'

